# Como remover acentos e outros sinais gráficos de uma String em Java?

Tags: java, string, acentuação

Como remover acentos e outros sinais gráficos de uma String em Java? Ex.:

```java
String s = "maçã";
String semAcento = ???; // resultado: "maca"
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Eu costumo usar `regex` junto com a classe `Normalizer`. Assim:

```java
public static String removerAcentos(String str) {
    return Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Se for Java7+ pode usar esta solução encontrada no SOen https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215117/1518921

Primeiro importe isto:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Depois adicione isto a sua classe principal ou a outra classe que use:

```
public static String deAccent(String str) {
    String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
```

E no momento de usar ficaria algo como:

```
System.out.print(deAccent("Olá, mundo!"));
```

Ele faz o uso da expressão regular ([regex](/questions/tagged/regex)) para as trocar: `\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+`

Veja funcionando no **IDEONE: https://ideone.com/MtgLAC**

Comment: Esta é a melhor resposta, porque só remove acentos, em vez de todos os caracteres não ASCII

Comment: @Mariano obrigado!! Estou formulando alguns detalhes pra explicar sobre o comportamento de ambas em ASCII e Unicode. Tem diferenças bem significativas, em breve irei detalhar ;)

Comment: Pode usar emoticons, letras gregas ou japonesas como exemplo ;-)

Comment: @Mariano então o comportamento será diferente, provavelmente da forma que esta será ignorado, é falta de tempo pra criar um exemplo descente, também não me recordo do comportamento "interno" já que quem faz o serviço sujo na verdade é o `Normalizer.normalize`, o `replaceAll` seria pra remover os inválidos. Tem uma resposta sobre o `InCombiningDiacriticalMarks` no site, mas eu achei ela muito fraca mesmo.