# Como remover acentuais em Java

Tags: java

Eu tenho um texto(parágrafo) que contem algumas palavras de utilizar acentuais, como por exemplo: **ne´ebé, oinsá, ne´ebá toallã, liña**,etc. Como é que posso tirar esses acentos na linguagem Java?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/remover-acentos-de-uma-string-em-java

Comment: Essa link é acertada! Obrigado #Vinicius Macelai